# How do I set up a global config for my app package that contains things like DB conn?

Tags: go

I've structured my application in two packages so far - `main` and `app`

In my `main()` I start my server:

```
func main() {
    router := app.CreateRouter(app.Routes())
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
}
```

In app, I have a `Config` struct which has a method `connectToDB`:

```
type Config struct {
    DB *sql.DB
}

func (c *Config) connectToDB() {
    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("user=%s password=%s dbname=%s sslmode=disable", os.Getenv("DB_USERNAME"), os.Getenv("DB_PASSWORD"), os.Getenv("DB_NAME"))
    var err error
    c.DB, err = sql.Open("postgres", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

func init() {
    c := Config{}
    c.connectToDB()
}
```

However, I have various handlers and if I want to make use of `Config.DB`, how can I do that?

For example, in app.UserIndex, how can I get to `Config.DB`?

```
func UserIndex(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "test!\n")
}
```

Now, one thing I can do is set a global variable, such as

`var c Config`

Then, I can access c.DB anywhere in package `app`.  However, this feels bad..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an `App` variable to keep there config and some other useful settings  for it eg Http time-out

```
var (
      App struct {
           DB         *sql.DB
           Timeout time.Duration
           ...
      }
)
```

Then make methods on this structure. This way config will be incapsulated in application instance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid globals, make your handlers structs instead of pure funcs:

```
type UserIndex struct {
    cfg Config
}

func (u UserIndex) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, "test!\n")
}
```

When setting up your routes, use `UserIndex{c}.ServeHTTP` instead of `UserIndex`.

The core library `http` package differentiates between a `Handler` type and a `HandlerFunc` for this reason.  You appear to be using `github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter`, which doesn't make this distinction and doesn't provide an `interface` that matches its `httprouter.Handle` type, but you can still use a method on a struct to satisfy that type.